# Accumulating Date Elements Across Hierarchies In A BizTalk Map

Tags: date, dictionary, biztalk, accumulate

( Please check my popup note at the bottom of this question before marking me down. Thank you! )

I have a problem in BizTalk where I am only able to achieve my desired mapping through multiple steps and would like to achieve the output using a single map.

An example of my input XML is as follows:-

```
<Books>
    <Book><Title>The BFG</Title><ISBN>0-224-02040-4</ISBN></Book>
    <Book><Title>The Hobbit</Title><ISBN>978-0261102217</ISBN></Book>
    <Book><Title>BizTalk Server 2010 Unleashed</Title><ISBN>978-0-672-33118-7</ISBN></Book> 
</Books>
<Revisions>
    <Revision><ISBN>0-224-02040-4</ISBN><Version>1</Version><Published>1970-08-22T00:00:00</Published></Revision>
    <Revision><ISBN>0-224-02040-4</ISBN><Version>2</Version><Published>1975-09-25T00:00:00</Published></Revision>
    <Revision><ISBN>0-224-02040-4</ISBN><Version>3</Version><Published>1990-09-16T00:00:00</Published></Revision>
    <Revision><ISBN>978-0-672-33118-7</ISBN><Version>1</Version><Published>2010-03-28T00:00:00</Published></Revision>
    <Revision><ISBN>978-0261102217</ISBN><Version>1</Version><Published>1960-09-25T00:00:00</Published></Revision>
    <Revision><ISBN>978-0-672-33118-7</ISBN><Version>2</Version><Published>2011-09-16T00:00:00</Published></Revision>
<Revisions>
```

My desired output XML for this example is:-

```
<HistoricBooks>
    <FirstIssue><ISBN>0-224-02040-4</ISBN><Title>The BFG</Title><FirstPublished>1970-08-22T00:00:00</FirstPublished><FirstIssue>
    <FirstIssue><ISBN>978-0261102217</ISBN><Title>The Hobbit</Title><FirstPublished>1960-09-25T00:00:00</FirstPublished><FirstIssue>
    <FirstIssue><ISBN>978-0-672-33118-7</ISBN><Title>BizTalk Server 2010 Unleashed</Title><FirstPublished>2010-03-28T00:00:00</FirstPublished><FirstIssue>
</HistoricBooks>
```

The first problem I have encountered is that BizTalk Minimum and CumulativeMinimum functoids both require numeric inputs and won’t work with dates. Therefore the first part of my question is...

**What is the best way to perform minimum and maximum functions on date elements in a BizTalk map?**

The second problem I have is with the way the cumulative functoids understand scope. The scope parameter indicates the depth at which to accumulate (entire document, parent, grandparent etc) but in this case it is not appropriate to simply take the minimum across all children of `<revisions>`. I need to be more selective. Therefore the second part of my question is...

**Which functoid should I use to perform the accumulation of dates selectively across my XML hierarchies and how should I achieve it?**

> I am aware this is two-fold question. I am also aware there are a number of ways of achieving the answers but many will result in complex, untidy and poorly performing code. I wish to avoid this. I am also aware this can be achieved easily by modifying the source or destination schemas or by not using BizTalk. These routes are not open to me. Therefore this question is asking for examples showing a simple, elegant BizTalk solution to the problem. If you don’t wish to provide an answer please do not punish a person who desires to improve his knowledge and skills.

Comment: First, this is a perfectly legitimate BizTalk question.  Second, I think you are way, way overthinking some things.  Please confirm one thing, all you want to do is merge the Title and FirstPublished data using ISBN as the key?

Comment: Hi Johns, yes, that's exactly right. And it is very likely I am overthinking it or missing something really obvious as my gut tells me this should be "bread and butter" for a BizTalk map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your overall solution.  There is one thing I would do differently.

Yes, use a Script Functoid to convert the date, but instead of difference, just take the .Ticks Property of the DateTime as input to the Cumulative Minimum.  This is returned as a Long.  Then, you're not dependent on any date and the output is deterministic.

Important, *there is absolutely nothing wrong with using a Two Map solution*.  This is a perfectly acceptable Pattern in BizTalk Dev.

You could probably do it in one Map, but that would require some inline Xslt Templates.  There's also nothing wrong with that.  But, a Two Map solution lets you use only built in Functoids.

Don't worry about 'performance' unless you can prove you need to.  The perf difference between one or two Maps will be barely measurable.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, I have worked around both parts of my question but the overall solution is not ideal and I would not recommend this as a good answer yet.

**Cumulative Minimum on Date Elements**

You can add a scripting functoid which uses inline C# to return the interval between the date element and a fixed date. Represent this interval in day and you have a numeric value which can be piped into your cumulative minimum functoid. Then simply use another scripting functoid to add the minimum interval back on to your fixed date.

For example, if we chose a fixed date of 2016-01-01 and our date elements contained 2016-01-03, 2016-01-04 and 2016-01-05 then our intervals would be 2, 3 and 4 days respectively. The cumulative minimum would be 2 and if we add 2 days back on to our fixed date of 2016-01-01 then our cumulative minimum date will be 2016-01-03.

**Performing Cumulative Functions Across Hierarchies**

This is a cheat which does not fully answer the question but my help other StackOverflow readers!

My very clunky workaround involves having an interim message schema with `<Revisions>` nodes as children of each `<Book>` node.

In step 1 I map from my source schema to my interim schema, copying the `<revisions>` node data into every `<Book>` node (I also store my calculated numeric interval here for convenience).

Then in step 2 I map from my interim schema to my output schema, using my minimum functoid and my scripting functoid to convert from my interval back to a date.

***Note: This two step solution means I am unable to use DateTime.Today as my fixed date as there is a risk the two steps may be executed on different days!***

Comment: Probably unimportant, but your spelling of <Revisions> is not consistent. Different casing.